# How to change the colour of everything in a tkinter GUI at once

Tags: python, user-interface, button, background, tkinter

I have some code (as shown below) which prompts the user to select which colour to change the GUI to. But my problem is that it only changes the background. I'd like to know if there's a way to change the background of every label and button at once or do I have to change each label/button individually.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()  
colour_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
options_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)

def colours():
    options_frame.pack_forget()
    red.pack()
    orange.pack()
    back_button.pack()
    colour_frame.pack()

def back():
    options_frame.pack()
    colour_frame.pack_forget()

def make_red():
    window.configure(background="red")

def make_orange():
    window.configure(background="orange")

colour_button = tkinter.Button(options_frame, text="Appearance", command=colours)

red = tkinter.Button(colour_frame, text="RED", command=make_red)
red.configure(bg = "red")
orange = tkinter.Button(colour_frame, text="ORANGE", command=make_orange)
orange.configure(bg = "orange")
back_button = tkinter.Button(colour_frame, text="Back", command=back)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a list containing all your widgets you want to change

```
myWidgets = [button1, label1, ... ] # List of widgets to change colour
for wid in myWidgets:
    wid.configure(bg = newColour)
```

Here's an example code of changing the background colour of multiple labels at once.

```
import tkinter as tk


# Change all label backgrounds
def change_colour():
    c = user.get() #Get the entered text of the Entry widget
    for wid in widget_list:
        wid.configure(bg = c)

# Create GUI
root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root, text='Enter a colour').pack()

user = tk.Entry(root)
user.pack()

label_frame = tk.Frame(root)
label_frame.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Change Colour', command = change_colour)
btn.pack()

widget_list = [user, btn] # Add defined widgets to list

#Dynamicly create labels for example
for x in range(10): 
    lbl = tk.Label(label_frame, text='Label '+str(x))
    lbl.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    widget_list.append(lbl) #Add widget object to list

root.mainloop()
```

Or if you have a Frame already containing all the widgets you want to change, then you can use this instead.

`parent_widget.winfo_children()` will return a list containing all the widgets stored inside the parent widget

```
def change_colour():
    c = user.get()
    for wid in label_frame.winfo_children():
        wid.configure(bg = c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ttk for some of your GUI elements.  ttk allows you to create styles for widgets and update the style to all widgets at once (at least for those that have the same style).  You may need to mix the usage of ttk and tkinter, but it should make things a bit easier in the long run.  Here is an example I made:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Creating a style for the buttons
color_style_button = ttk.Style()
color_style_button.configure("color.TButton", foreground="red")

def change_color(color):
    # This function changes the style to all buttons using the "color.Button style"

    if color == "red":
        color_style_button.configure("color.TButton", foreground="red")
    elif color == "blue":
        color_style_button.configure("color.TButton", foreground="blue")
    elif color == "green":
        color_style_button.configure("color.TButton", foreground="green")

frame_a = ttk.Frame(root)
frame_a.pack()

red_button = ttk.Button(frame_a, text="Red", command=lambda: change_color("red"), style="color.TButton")
red_button.pack()

blue_button = ttk.Button(frame_a, text="Blue", command=lambda: change_color("blue"), style="color.TButton")
blue_button.pack()

green_button = ttk.Button(frame_a, text="Blue", command=lambda: change_color("green"), style="color.TButton")
green_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I recommend checking out [this site](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) to learn more about ttk and styles.