# Deleting a Label widget created in a For Loop (Tkinter)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter, label

This code is part of a program I'm developing. It uses CSV to read from a file. This part of the code is supposed to compare the input date to the dates in the CSV file and output any matching dates and the information they carry. This is the CSV data: [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fEp.png)
The problem is, when I input another date in the filed, I want it to delete any labels created in the for loop of the code. The deleteResults function only deletes the last set of labels created. Is there a way to delete via another function all the labels created in the for loop, not mattering the amount of labels created with the for loop? Thanks.

```
#PLANNER
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from csv import*
import csv

colW=['#000000','#f9f4bd','#fff200','black','#2378c8','#ed1c24']
colSch=colW

accessDayPage=False
results=False

existingEvents=[]
eventsFile=open("dayFile.csv","r+")
evImport=csv.reader(eventsFile)
for row in evImport:
    existingEvents.append(row)


def deleteResults():
    global dateLabel,descriptionLabel,titleLabel,results
    if results==True:
        dateLabel.destroy()
        descriptionLabel.destroy()
        titleLabel.destroy()
        evTypeLabel.destroy()
        results=False
def destroyaccessDay():
    global accessDayPage
    if accessDayPage==True:
        accessD.destroy()
        accessM.destroy()
        accessY.destroy()
        slash.destroy()
        slash1.destroy()
        accessButton.destroy()

        accessDayPage=False

def go():
    global dayAcc,existingEvents,dateLabel,descriptionLabel,titleLabel,dayAccFORSEARCH,eventsCreated,evTypeLabel,results
    deleteResults()
    lineforevent=93
    leDay="0"
    leMon="404"
    if accessD.get()=="01":
        leDay="1"
    elif accessD.get()=="02":
        leDay="2"
    elif accessD.get()=="03":
        leDay="3"
    elif accessD.get()=="04":
        leDay="4"
    elif accessD.get()=="05":
        leDay="5"
    elif accessD.get()=="06":
        leDay="6"
    elif accessD.get()=="07":
        leDay="7"
    elif accessD.get()=="08":
        leDay="8"
    elif accessD.get()=="09":
        leDay="9"
    elif accessD.get()=="1":
        leDay="1"
    elif accessD.get()=="2":
        leDay="2"
    elif accessD.get()=="3":
        leDay="3"
    elif accessD.get()=="4":
        leDay="4"
    elif accessD.get()=="5":
        leDay="5"
    elif accessD.get()=="6":
        leDay="6"
    elif accessD.get()=="7":
        leDay="7"
    elif accessD.get()=="8":
        leDay="8"
    elif accessD.get()=="9":
        leDay="9"
    elif accessD.get()=="10":
        leDay="10"
    elif accessD.get()=="11":
        leDay="11"
    elif accessD.get()=="12":
        leDay="12"
    elif accessD.get()=="13":
        leDay="13"
    elif accessD.get()=="14":
        leDay="14"
    elif accessD.get()=="15":
        leDay="15"
    elif accessD.get()=="16":
        leDay="16"
    elif accessD.get()=="17":
        leDay="17"
    elif accessD.get()=="18":
        leDay="18"
    elif accessD.get()=="19":
        leDay="19"
    elif accessD.get()=="20":
        leDay="20"
    elif accessD.get()=="21":
        leDay="21"
    elif accessD.get()=="22":
        leDay="22"
    elif accessD.get()=="23":
        leDay="23"
    elif accessD.get()=="24":
        leDay="24"
    elif accessD.get()=="25":
        leDay="25"
    elif accessD.get()=="26":
        leDay="26"
    elif accessD.get()=="27":
        leDay="27"
    elif accessD.get()=="28":
        leDay="28"
    elif accessD.get()=="29":
        leDay="29"
    elif accessD.get()=="30":
        leDay="30"
    elif accessD.get()=="31":
        leDay="31"

    if accessM.get()=="1":
        leMon="January"
    elif accessM.get()=="01":
        leMon="January"
    elif accessM.get()=="2":
        leMon="February"
    elif accessM.get()=="02":
        leMon="February"
    elif accessM.get()=="3":
        leMon="March"
    elif accessM.get()=="03":
        leMon="March"
    elif accessM.get()=="4":
        leMon="April"
    elif accessM.get()=="04":
        leMon="April"
    elif accessM.get()=="5":
        leMon="May"
    elif accessM.get()=="05":
        leMon="May"
    elif accessM.get()=="6":
        leMon="June"
    elif accessM.get()=="06":
        leMon="June"
    elif accessM.get()=="7":
        leMon="July"
    elif accessM.get()=="07":
        leMon="July"
    elif accessM.get()=="8":
        leMon="August"
    elif accessM.get()=="08":
        leMon="August"
    elif accessM.get()=="9":
        leMon="September"
    elif accessM.get()=="09":
        leMon="September"
    elif accessM.get()=="10":
        leMon="October"
    elif accessM.get()=="10":
        leMon="October"
    elif accessM.get()=="11":
        leMon="November"
    elif accessM.get()=="11":
        leMon="November"
    elif accessM.get()=="12":
        leMon="December"
    elif accessM.get()=="12":
        leMon="December"
    dayAcc=str(leDay+leMon+accessY.get())
    dayAccFORSEARCH=str(dayAcc+"'")



    for i in existingEvents:
        global results
        if i[0]==dayAccFORSEARCH:            
            deleteResults()

            titleLabel=tkinter.Label(main, text=i[1],fg=colSch[3],bg=colSch[1],font=("DFKai-SB",9,"bold"))
            titleLabel.place(x=140,y=lineforevent)
            evTypeLabel=tkinter.Label(main, text=i[2],fg=colSch[4],bg=colSch[0],font=("Consolas",9))
            evTypeLabel.place(x=320,y=lineforevent)
            descriptionLabel=tkinter.Label(main,text=i[3],fg=colSch[5],bg=colSch[1],font=("Garamond",9))
            descriptionLabel.place(x=420,y=lineforevent)
            lineforevent+=35

    dateLabel=tkinter.Label(main, text=dayAcc,fg=colSch[4],bg=colSch[0],font=("Consolas",12))
    dateLabel.place(x=140,y=35)
    results=True



def accessDay():

    destroyaccessDay()
    deleteResults()

    global accessD,accessM,accessY,slash,slash1,accessButton,accessDayPage

    accessD=tkinter.Entry(main,width=2)
    accessD.place(x=140, y=8)
    slash=tkinter.Label(main,text="/",fg=colSch[4],bg=colSch[0],font=("14"))
    slash.place(x=160,y=8)
    accessM=tkinter.Entry(main,width=2)
    accessM.place(x=175, y=8)
    slash1=tkinter.Label(main,text="/",fg=colSch[4],bg=colSch[0],font=("14"))
    slash1.place(x=195,y=8)
    accessY=tkinter.Entry(main,width=4)
    accessY.place(x=210, y=8)
    accessButton=tkinter.Button(main, text="Go",bg=colSch[2],fg=colSch[4],width=6,height=1, font=("Copperplate Gothic Light","9"),command=go)##
    accessButton.place(x=245,y=8)

    accessDayPage=True




main=tkinter.Tk()
main.configure(bg=colSch[0])
main.geometry('780x375')
w=Canvas(main,width=780,height=375)
w.pack()
rect1=w.create_rectangle(0,0,775,375,fill=colSch[0])
rect2=w.create_rectangle(0,0,120,375,fill=colSch[1])

accessDay=tkinter.Button(main,text="Access Day",bg=colSch[2],fg=colSch[4],width=15,height=3,relief=FLAT, font=("Bernard MT Condensed","11"),command=accessDay)
accessDay.place(x=5,y=5)





main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that the method is similar to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322686/how-to-change-the-colour-of-everything-in-a-tkinter-gui-at-once/33325940#33325940) where the example I gave uses dynamicly generated widgets. You'll want to look at `.destoy()` instead of `.configure()`

**Side notes:**

I would suggest use `in` for your if statements to shorten the code since you are performing the same operation for a different instance.

```
if accessM.get() in {"1", "01"}:
    leMon="January"
```

Alternatively as Bryan Oakley suggested. Using a dictionary. I believe it would be something like this.

```
date_values = {"01" : ("January", range(1, 31)),
               "02" : ("February", range(1, 30)), # Check for leap years
               .....}

leMon = date_values[accessM.get()][0]
d = int(accessD.get())
# Checks if day is in month range
leDay = str(d) if d in date_values[accessM.get()][1] else None
```

Comment: Even better than `in` is to create a dictionary or list, and use the value of the entry field to look up the item.  Those 24 lines of code can be reduced down to three or four.

Comment: True, forgot about that. Is this how it would be done?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I've only been using python for about half a year, so I didn't know of the existence of dictionaries really. Thanks for the help.