# How do I efficiently change all the buttons in my program?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, background, widget

I have coded multiple buttons in my Tkinter program, and I want to change the text colour of all of them to blue. I know I could type 'fg="blue"'every time I create a new button, but I'm looking for a way to select all the buttons in my program, and change the background colour of all of them at the same time.
So far I've tried

```
for AllButtons in (Button1, Button, ect.)
```

But it still takes a long time and I'll have to add to the list every time I make a new button. What's the most efficient way of changing the text colour of all the buttons in my program?

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322686/how-to-change-the-colour-of-everything-in-a-tkinter-gui-at-once

Comment: Yes but I was hoping for a more efficient way than what was said in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ttk widgets and their style to change the appearance of all of the widgets of a specific class at once.

Consider the following example, clicking on the change style button will change the text color from red to blue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('300x110')
        self.resizable(0, 0)

        self.style = ttk.Style(self)
        self.style.configure('W.TButton', foreground = 'red')

        # login button
        login_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Login",style="W.TButton")
        login_button.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E)

        change_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Change Style",style="W.TButton", command=self.changeStyle)
        change_button.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky=tk.E)



    def changeStyle(self):
        print("Change")
        self.style.configure('W.TButton', foreground='blue')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

All of the buttons are mapped to a "W.TButton" style so when we change that style, all of the widgets associated with that style will change their appearance.

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution I haven't thought of.